# Can't requestQuota for files since Chrome 86

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fileapi, file-access

I recently tried to update one of my former webapp project in which I need to download files from a server and store them on the device (to access it later).
In order to achieve this I use the navigator.persistentStorage (or navigator.webkitPersistentStorage) and its requestQuota function as seen in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem#using_persistent_storage

The issue is that, when I test my application locally (accessing the index.html via file:///) the requestQuota triggers the "Do you want to allow" chrome popup but when I select "Yes" I get a failure with following DOMError :

```
{
   message: "The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation."
   name: "NotSupportedError"
}
```

On the other hand, when I access the application deployed on its distant server everything works like a charm.

Beeing aware of the restrictions of the file API in local (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction#file), I ran thoses tests with a custom chrome :
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ssl-version-min=tls1 --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\tmp\chromeDev"

To test it outside of my application environment, I tried the simple line in chrome inspect :

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024,
   r => console.log('success'),
   e => console.log('failure : ' + e)
);
```

On a random local index.html openened in chrome (with file:///) --> "failure".
On a random website (with https://) --> "success".

I downgraded my Chrome and found out all of this problem only occurs since **Chrome 86**.

Ideally I should upgrade my application to use IndexedDb API, but in the short run a fix or workaround would be quite welcome :)

Thx